# How to type the union of a single parameter and rest parameters with typescript?

Tags: typescript

if I have a function that takes either an object or a list of items as parameters,

```
f1 = (p: Object) => ...
f1 = (...p: string[]) => ...
```

this is what I want to achieve, but apparently it doesn't work:

```
f1 = (p: Object | ...p: string[]) => ...
```

how do I type this kind of 'union'?

Comment: I think you can't. But you can do something like this `f1 = ( ...p: string[] |Object[])  ...` It will fit your need but it will allow passing multiple objects as array.

Comment: yeah, probably the best we can do. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overloads for function declarations or tuples in rest parameters:

```
const f1 = (...p: [object] | string[]) => { }
f1({})
f1({}, {}) //err
f1("")
f1("", '')
```